# Is it possible to place a button instead of view in a UIPopoverController?

Tags: ipad

I am new to iPad application and trying to place a popover, can I place use button as a view for popover?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A button is a view, so why not?

Comment: am getting this exception Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] must not be called with `nil`.'

Answer (score 1):

With regard to your comment on Erik B's answer:

If you read the method name: `initWithContentViewController:` and then read the error message that it must not be called with nil as an argument, you should arrive at your problem.

The popover controller expects you to pass in a valid view controller instance. If you want the view of your view controller to be a button, that's a not a problem, but you must provide a view controller to the popover controller.

Comment: Your button can either be a subview of a view managed by a view controller or the actual view managed by the view controller.

Comment: custom button displays black background.. is it possible to make it transparent?

Comment: I have answered the original question. If you have further questions, please create new questions for them.